# Zend Framework URL Without mod_rewrite

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

In a scenario where I don't have mod_rewrite installed, is there any easy way to make URLs like from same regex router

> http://www.example.com/module=admin&controller=user&action=index&param1=12&param2=37

and Zend Framework should be able to dispatch controller by reading the same format.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to change host. Media Temple is the bomb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob Allen had a blog post about `Zend Framework URLs without mod_rewrite`

to be honest i didn't try it , but it worth mentioning

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-urls-without-mod_rewrite/

Comment: haha the Rob's blog title is exactly as your question's title :)

Comment: thanks @tawfekov, for your response an this is merely a coincidence that my question and this tutorial have exactly same title. I am not that naive to create the question with exactly same title.

Comment: though its good article and i am confident its the solution, i will probably try it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure the easiest way to get this working with ZF is like this:

```
http://www.site.com/index.php/admin/user/index/param1/12/param2/37
```

As in, simply put index.php before your parameters. This way Apache should route the request to index.php.

You may need to set your ZF base URL as follows:

```
//assuming $fc is front controller
$fc->setBaseUrl('/index.php');
```

Pretty sure the default router can handle it like this. If not, you could extend the router which shouldn't be too difficult if you just look at the code of the existing one for tips.

Comment: Are you sure this scheme will not need mod_rewrite? because i m.